# Can I get the date at which a location started to exist in Azure maps?

Tags: azure-maps

I'm looking to understand the age of stores in Azure maps.

Does Azure provide a way to query when a particular store opened?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Maps doesn't have that information in their services. To be honest, I haven't seen that in any service from anyone.

Comment: I got some progress by querying OpenStreetMap "Attic" (archive) data. They take regular snapshots of their mapping database and let you query the snapshots - but the quality is not what you'd want.

Comment: That likely only has the date the location was added to OSM which will likely not be anywhere close to when it initially opened. I'm assuming when you say opened, you are looking for a historical date, not the time of day it opens.